# Cannot fit er-example-server to TelosB

Tags: contiki, sky

I am trying to make 2 motes connect via a border-router, using the contiki 3 examples. I compiled er-example-client but it does not fit on my Crossbow TelosB mote. It comes up with error message:

> er-example-server.sky section '.text' will not fit in region 'rom'

I am using Instant Contiki, which has msp430-gcc v4.7. The same seems to happen in Cooja as well, using Sky motes.

Comment: May be there is a lack of memory in TelosB?

Answer (score 2):

The application doesn't fit the Sky/TelosB ROM.  Using the `msp430-4.7.x` provides a nice size reduction, but doesn't seem to benefit the Sky.  Try disabling some of the resources enabled by default, for example compiling only with the `hello` test yields:

```
msp430-size er-example-server.sky 
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  48669     278    8646   57593    e0f9 er-example-server.sky
```