# Section will not fit in region 'rom'

Tags: c, contiki

I have git-cloned the latest contiki-master. Now I need to print debug messages from [sicslowpan.c](https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/blob/master/core/net/ipv6/sicslowpan.c). If `#define DEBUG DEBUG_NONE` the simulation works, but if I set `#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT` in `sicslowpan.c` I get the following error even for `hello-world.c` on sky motes. I haven't touched any of the other files.
How do I get rid of this error?

```
/usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: hello-world.sky section `.rodata' will not fit in region `rom'
/usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: section .vectors loaded at [0000ffe0,0000ffff] overlaps section .rodata loaded at [0000f590,000100b0]
/usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/../../../../msp430/bin/ld: region `rom' overflowed by 456 bytes
/usr/local/msp430/bin/../lib/gcc/msp430/4.7.0/mmpy-16/libcrt0.a(_copy_data.o): In function `__do_copy_data':
/home/user/building-mspgcc/gcc-4.7.0-msp430/msp430/mmpy-16/libgcc/../../../../gcc-4.7.0/libgcc/config/msp430/crt0.S:208:(.init4+0x12): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16_BYTE against symbol `__data_load_start' defined in *ABS* section in hello-world.sky
obj_sky/contiki-sky-main.o: In function `main':
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:302:(.init9+0x176): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `contikimac_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(contikimac.o)
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:303:(.init9+0x17a): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `csma_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(csma.o)
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:304:(.init9+0x17e): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `nullsec_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(nullsec.o)
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:307:(.init9+0x186): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `contikimac_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(contikimac.o)
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:307:(.init9+0x1b4): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `contikimac_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(contikimac.o)
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:307:(.init9+0x1b8): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `csma_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(csma.o)
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../platform/sky/./contiki-sky-main.c:307:(.init9+0x1bc): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `nullsec_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(nullsec.o)
contiki-sky.a(cc2420.o): In function `cc2420_init':
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../dev/cc2420/cc2420.c:635:(.text.process_thread_cc2420_process+0x3c): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `contikimac_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(contikimac.o)
Process returned error code 2
contiki-sky.a(sicslowpan.o): In function `sicslowpan_get_last_rssi':
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../core/net/ipv6/sicslowpan.c:1797:(.text.send_packet+0x12): relocation truncated to fit: R_MSP430_16 against symbol `nullsec_driver' defined in .rodata section in contiki-sky.a(nullsec.o)
/home/user/contiki/examples/hello-world/../../core/net/ipv6/sicslowpan.c:1797:(.text.output+0x32): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [hello-world.sky] Error 1
```

P.S: For someone who is trying to close the question without conveying the reason please understand that the question is not `too-broad` or `primarily opinion-based`.

Comment: when you define `#define DEBUG DEBUG_PRINT` you enable some debug code which increases code size. I guess you don't have the room for that.

Comment: Get a larger device or strip down your code.The message is very clear!

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: In contiki 2.7 I could print debug messages from sicslowpan.c for C source file having size larger than hello-world.c.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot fit er-example-server to TelosB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35894400/cannot-fit-er-example-server-to-telosb)

Comment: I really understand what the error means because I had asked this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42020249/configuration-msp430-unknown-none-not-supported.

Answer (score 2):

**you first line error**:world.sky section `.rodata' will not fit in region`rom'.

so try to use Z1(92 KB)ROM instate of sky mote(48 KB)ROM.